# Alternate of lead lag function in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to compare the current row with a value in the next row. SQL has `LEAD` and `LAG` functions to get the next and previous values but I can not use them because I am using SQL Server 2008.

So how do I get this?

I have table with output

```
+----+-------+-----------+-------------------------+
| Id | ActId |  StatusId |       MinStartTime      |
+----+-------+-----------+-------------------------+
| 1  |  42   | 1         | 2014-02-14 11:17:21.203 |
| 2  |  42   | 1         | 2014-02-14 11:50:19.367 |
| 3  |  42   | 1         | 2014-02-14 11:50:19.380 |
| 4  |  42   | 6         | 2014-02-17 05:25:57.280 |
| 5  |  42   | 6         | 2014-02-19 06:09:33.150 |
| 6  |  42   | 1         | 2014-02-19 06:11:24.393 |
| 7  |  42   | 6         | 2014-02-19 06:11:24.410 |
| 8  |  42   | 8         | 2014-02-19 06:44:47.070 |
+----+-------+-----------+-------------------------+
```

What I want to do is if the current row status is 1 and the next row status is 6 and both times are the same (up to minutes) then I want to get the row where the status is 1.

Eg: Id 6 row has status 1 and Id 7 row has status 6 but both times are the same ie. 2014-02-19 06:11

So I want to get this row or id for status 1 ie. id 6

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your case, the `id`s appear to be numeric, you can just do a self-join:

```
select t.*
from table t join
     table tnext
     on t.id = tnext.id - 1 and
        t.StatusId = 1 and
        tnext.StatusId = 6 and
        datediff(second, t.MinStartTime, tnext.MinStartTime) < 60;
```

This isn't quite the same minute.  It is within 60 seconds.  Do you actually need the same calendar time minute?  If so, you can do:

```
select t.*
from table t join
     table tnext
     on t.id = tnext.id - 1 and
        t.StatusId = 1 and
        tnext.StatusId = 6 and
        datediff(second, t.MinStartTime, tnext.MinStartTime) < 60 and
        datepart(minute, t.MinStartTime) = datepart(minute, tnext.MinStartTime);
```

Comment: Perhaps the above solution assumes no holes in the Id column.

Comment: Thanks for ur time and perfect solution ... i was comparing time as CONVERT(char(16),t1.MinStartTime,120) .. so it will return time upto minutes...is this wrong approach ?

Comment: @Spenzo . . . No, that's a fine approach.  But who can remember all the formats for `convert()`, so I tend to find other solutions (such as the one in the answer).

Comment: Followed up with a more complex multi table join based on Gordon's excellent answer.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff. You are always a superstar :)

Answer (score 0):

Just posting a more complex join using two different tables created with Gordon's foundation.  Excuse the specific object names, but you'll get the gist.  Gets the percentage change in samples from one to the next.

```
SELECT 
      fm0.SAMPLE curFMSample
    , fm1.SAMPLE nextFMSample
    , fm0.TEMPERATURE curFMTemp
    , fm1.TEMPERATURE nextFMTemp
    , ABS(CAST((fm0.Temperature - fm1.Temperature) AS DECIMAL(4, 0)) / CAST(fm0.TEMPERATURE AS DECIMAL(4, 0))) AS fmTempChange
    , fm0.GAUGE curFMGauge
    , fm1.GAUGE nextFMGauge
    , ABS(CAST((fm0.GAUGE - fm1.GAUGE) AS DECIMAL(4, 4)) / CAST(fm0.GAUGE AS DECIMAL(4, 4))) AS fmGaugeChange
    , fm0.WIDTH curFMWidth
    , fm1.WIDTH nextFMWidth
    , ABS(CAST((fm0.Width - fm1.Width) AS DECIMAL(4, 2)) / CAST(fm0.Width AS DECIMAL(4, 2))) AS fmWidthChange
    , cl0.TEMPERATURE curClrTemp
    , cl1.TEMPERATURE nextClrTemp
    , ABS(CAST((cl0.Temperature - cl1.Temperature) AS DECIMAL(4, 0)) / CAST(cl0.TEMPERATURE AS DECIMAL(4, 0))) AS clrTempChange
FROM 
    dbo.COIL_FINISHING_MILL_EXIT_STR02 fm0
    INNER JOIN dbo.COIL_FINISHING_MILL_EXIT_STR02 fm1 ON (fm0.SAMPLE = fm1.SAMPLE - 1 AND fm1.coil = fm0.coil)
    INNER JOIN dbo.COIL_COILER_STR02 cl0 ON fm0.coil = cl0.coil AND fm0.SAMPLE = cl0.SAMPLE
    INNER JOIN dbo.COIL_COILER_STR02 cl1 ON (cl0.SAMPLE = cl1.SAMPLE - 1 AND cl1.coil = cl0.coil)
WHERE
    fm0.coil = 2015515872
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would suggest a very simple solution if you do not have a sequential row id but a different step (if some records were deleted for example..):

```
declare @t table(id int, obj_name varchar(5))

insert @t select 1,'a'

insert @t select 5,'b'

insert @t select 22,'c'

insert @t select 543,'d'

---------------------------------
select *from @t
```

Example Source Table @t:

```
---------------------------------
id  obj_name

1   a

5   b

22  c

543 d

---------------------------------
```

Select with self join

```
select obj_name_prev=tt.obj_name, obj_name_next=min(t.obj_name)

from @t t

join @t tt on tt.id < t.id

group by tt.obj_name
```

Result:

```
---------------------------------
obj_name_prev   obj_name_next

a   b

b   c

c   d

---------------------------------
```