# Updating a table to avoid overlapping dates

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, overlapping

I am trying to write a query that reorders date ranges around particular spans. It should do something that looks like this

```
Member   Rank   Begin Date   End Date
2275     A      9/9/14       11/17/14
2275     B      9/26/14      3/24/15
2275     B      3/25/15      12/31/15
8983     A      9/16/13      3/10/15
8983     B      2/24/15      4/28/15
8983     A      4/28/15      12/31/15
```

and have it become

```
Member   Rank   Begin Date   End Date
2275     A      9/9/14       11/17/14
2275     B      11/18/14     3/24/15
2275     B      3/25/15      12/31/15
8983     A      9/16/13      3/10/15
8983     B      3/11/15      4/27/15
8983     A      4/28/15      12/31/15
```

To explain further,  I am looking to update the dates. There isn't much to the ranking except A > B. And there is only A and B. Date ranges with rank A should remain untouched. Overlapping B ranked dates are okay. I am concerned with B ranked dates overlapping with A ranked dates. The table is very large (~700 members) and with several different members IDs. The 2nd line (Rank B) of member 2275 changes the begin date to 11/18/15 to not overlap with the 1st line.

I am using  Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LATEST EDIT: Here's what I did for pre-2012. I don't think it's the most elegant solution.

```
WITH a AS (
    SELECT
        1 AS lgoffset
        , NULL AS lgdefval
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Member] ORDER BY [Begin Date]) AS seq
        , [Member]
        , [Rank]
        , [Begin Date]
        , [End Date]
    FROM #table 
)
SELECT
    a.seq
    , a.[Member]
    , a.[Rank]
    , a.[Begin Date]
    , CASE
        WHEN a.[Rank] = 'B' AND a.[Begin Date] <= ISNULL(aLag.[End Date], a.lgdefval)
        THEN ISNULL(aLag.[End Date], a.lgdefval)
        ELSE a.[Begin Date]
      END AS bdate2
    , a.[End Date]
INTO #b
FROM a
LEFT OUTER JOIN a aLag
    ON a.seq = aLag.seq + a.lgoffset
    AND a.[Member] = aLag.[Member]
ORDER BY [Member], [Begin Date];


UPDATE #table
SET #table.bdate = CASE
                    WHEN #table.rnk = 'B' AND #table.bdate <= (SELECT #b.bdate2 FROM #b WHERE #b.bdate2 > #b.bdate and #table.mbr = #b.mbr)
                    THEN dateadd(d, 1,(SELECT bdate2 FROM #b WHERE #b.bdate2 > #b.bdate and #table.mbr = #b.mbr )) 
                    ELSE #table.bdate
                    END
```

**EDIT PS: Below was my previous answer that only applies to 2012 and later.**

You may want to try the following `SELECT` statement to see if you get the desired results and then convert to an `UPDATE`:

```
SELECT 
[Member]
, [Rank]
, CASE
    WHEN [Rank] = 'B' AND [Begin Date] <= LAG([End Date],1,'12/31/2030') OVER(PARTITION BY [Member] ORDER BY [Begin Date]) 
    THEN DATEADD(d,1,LAG([End Date],1,'12/31/2030')OVER(PARTITION BY [Member] ORDER BY [Begin Date]))
    ELSE [Begin Date]
  END AS [Begin Date]
, [End Date]
FROM #Table
ORDER BY [Member], [Begin Date]
```

EDIT: So in order to update the begin date column:

```
UPDATE #Table
SET [Begin Date] = (SELECT
                    CASE
                        WHEN [Rank] = 'B' AND [Begin Date] <= LAG([End Date],1,'12/31/2030') OVER(PARTITION BY [Member] ORDER BY [Begin Date]) 
                        THEN DATEADD(d,1,LAG([End Date],1,'12/31/2030')OVER(PARTITION BY [Member] ORDER BY [Begin Date]))
                        ELSE [Begin Date]
                      END AS [Begin Date]
                    FROM #Table)
```

EDIT 2: Some of my code was incorrect due to not realizing the lag function needed an OVER statement, updated select statement and update statement

Sources:[Alternate of lead lag function in sql server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22188514/alternate-of-lead-lag-function-in-sql-server-2008)

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/11/24/sql-server-solution-to-puzzle-simulate-lead-and-lag-without-using-sql-server-2012-analytic-function/

Comment: yeah i am using an update query, however i am finding it difficult to isolate each member individually  



`update #table 
set begindate = DATEADD(d, 1, 
(select b.enddate
from #table b 
where b.rank = 'A'   
and b.begindate < enddate 
and b.member= member)  
)  
where rank = 'B'`

Comment: You may have to change the variables to fit your table variables.

Comment: I dont believe LAG is functional in SQL server 2008

Comment: Just checked msdn and I was wrong. Sorry for the wild goose chase. I'll keep thinking...