# What is the alternative of LAG in SQL Server 2008 from SQL Server 2014?

Tags: function, sql-server-2008, lag

I have code like this. How to translate this for use in SQL Server 2008 since it does not have the `LAG` function?

Thanks in advance

```
CASE 
   WHEN ISNULL(LAG([a].[Client Key]) OVER (PARTITION BY [client key] 
                                           ORDER BY [Client key]),0 ) <> a.[Client Key] 
      THEN a.WIPClientLevel 
      ELSE 0 
END
```

Comment: A quick google comes up with this ... http://stackoverflow.com/q/22188514/512365

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alternate of lead lag function in sql server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22188514/alternate-of-lead-lag-function-in-sql-server-2008)