# left join to previous record in same table based on datetime column

Tags: sql-server, left-join

I have a table that contains details of when a Member has visited.

I want to do a left join to previous record in same table based on a datetime column

When I look at the visit data I also want to see when their previous visit was so I can calculate how long it was between visits. The VisitDateTime column is a datetime datatype. The table potentially has hundreds of millions of rows in it.

**Example Data:**

```
MemberID VisitDateTime
1        2016-01-01 10:00:00.000
2        2016-01-01 10:01:00.000
1        2016-01-01 11:00:00.000
2        2016-01-01 11:30:00.000
3        2016-01-01 11:45:00.000
1        2016-01-01 11:50:00.000
```

So I'm trying to join a table back onto itself, with the previous Visit.VisitDateTime for that Member displayed as a `PreviousVisitDateTime` column:

**Desired Result:**

```
MemberID VisitDateTime           PreviousVisitDateTime
1        2016-01-01 10:00:00.000 null
2        2016-01-01 10:01:00.000 null
1        2016-01-01 11:00:00.000 2016-01-01 10:00:00.000
2        2016-01-01 11:30:00.000 2016-01-01 10:01:00.000
3        2016-01-01 11:45:00.000 null
1        2016-01-01 11:50:00.000 2016-01-01 11:00:00.000
```

But I can't even imagine how I'd go about doing this.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont specify which version of SQL Server, so for SQL Server 2012 onwards:

```
CREATE TABLE #Test (MemberID INT, VisitDateTime DATETIME);

INSERT INTO #Test(MemberID, VisitDateTime) VALUES
(1, '2016-01-01 10:00:00.000'),
(2, '2016-01-01 10:01:00.000'),
(1, '2016-01-01 11:00:00.000'),
(2, '2016-01-01 11:30:00.000'),
(3, '2016-01-01 11:45:00.000'),
(1, '2016-01-01 11:50:00.000') 

SELECT MemberID
      ,VisitDateTime,
      LAG(VisitDateTime) OVER (PARTITION BY MemberID ORDER BY VisitDateTime) PreviousVisit FROM #Test
      ORDER BY VisitDateTime;


  MemberID    VisitDateTime           PreviousVisit
----------- ----------------------- -----------------------
1           2016-01-01 10:00:00.000 NULL
2           2016-01-01 10:01:00.000 NULL
1           2016-01-01 11:00:00.000 2016-01-01 10:00:00.000
2           2016-01-01 11:30:00.000 2016-01-01 10:01:00.000
3           2016-01-01 11:45:00.000 NULL
1           2016-01-01 11:50:00.000 2016-01-01 11:00:00.000
```

And to simulate `LAG` in 2008, try [Alternate of lead lag function in sql server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22188514/alternate-of-lead-lag-function-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: Thanks Les, that's a fantastic answer, I've learnt a really useful new SQL trick!

Comment: No problem. Here's some more handy refs https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it with a left join:

```
SELECT a.MemberID, a.Visitdatetime,MIN(b.visitdatetime)
FROM #Test a
LEFT JOIN #Test b on b.MemberID=a.MemberID and b.visitDateTime < a.visitDateTime
GROUP BY a.MemberID,a.VisitDateTime
ORDER BY a.visitdatetime
```

Comment: Thanks David, this works, but it takes a couple of minutes across 200K records whereas the LAG / PARTITION solution is sub 1 second.

Comment: I know it isn't the optimal solution. I saw the other answer (which is better) before I posted this.  I just thought i should mention it since your original question specifically asked for the left join logic :-)