# How can we use LAG() in SQL server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN ser.[Department Name] = LAG(SER.[Department Name]) OVER (ORDER BY SER.[Department Name]) THEN ''
    ELSE SER.[Department Name]
  END [Department Name] from department
```

Comment: By upgrading to a supported version of sql server. LAG was not available in 2008R2 so there is no way you can make it work, it doesn't exist. But you really need to consider upgrading. That version has been unsupported for several months now.

Comment: You can try with other window functions like DENSE_RANK with the combination of recursive CTE. Both DENSE_RANK and CTEs are available in 2K8R2

Comment: Any alternate of LAG() function in 2008R2

Comment: One solution would be to use a Left/Self Joined CTE linked by a sequence derived from ROW_NUMBER() or some variation. Then use aggregates on the self joined lead or lag table.

Comment: An *alternative* to `LAG` (you can't alternate a `LAG`) would be aCTE, `ROW_NUMBER` and a self referencing CTE. But the real solution is upgrade.

Comment: The reason LAG was created is because the logic to find the "previous" row is rather painful and requires a lot of hoops to jump through.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Alternate of lead lag function in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22188514/alternate-of-lead-lag-function-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: Not yet. I am trying to implement this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `APPLY` :

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN d.[Department Name] = Prev_Dept
             THEN '' ELSE d.[Department Name]
        END) AS DepartmentName
FROM department d OUTER APPLY
     ( SELECT TOP (1) d1.[Department Name] AS Prev_Dept
       FROM department d1
       WHERE d1.? < d.?
       ORDER BY ? DESC
     ) AS Pd;
```

`?` indicates identify column that identifies unique sequence of data.