# Get the first row in the group of dates where there is a sequence of dates with no break

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, gaps-and-islands

```
DECLARE @TestData TABLE (
    Idntty    Int    Not Null
    ,[DATE] DATE NOT NULL
    ,[TYPE] VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
    )
INSERT INTO @TestData VALUES 
(1,  '2016-03-01', 'Inventory'),
(2,  '2016-04-01', 'Inventory'), 
(3,  '2016-06-01', 'Inventory'),  
(4,  '2016-07-01', 'Inventory'), 
(5,  '2016-08-01', 'Inventory'),  
(6,  '2016-09-01', 'Inventory'),
(7,  '2017-01-01', 'Inventory'), 
(8,  '2017-02-01', 'Inventory'),  
(9,  '2017-03-01', 'Inventory'),
;
```

Basically I need to get the first row in the ***LAST*** group where there is a sequence of dates with no break.

for example here '2016-03-01' can't be right because '2016-05-01' is missing, so there is a break in sequence for this date record.

Criteria for grouping is continuous dates, so here in example there are 3 groups as there are 2 breaks, one because '2016-06-01' is missing and second because '2016-10-01', '2016-11-01', '2016-12-01' are missing:

```
(1,  '2016-03-01', 'Inventory'),
(2,  '2016-04-01', 'Inventory'),

and

(3,  '2016-06-01', 'Inventory'),  
(4,  '2016-07-01', 'Inventory'), 
(5,  '2016-08-01', 'Inventory'),  
(6,  '2016-09-01', 'Inventory'), 

and

(7,  '2017-01-01', 'Inventory'), 
(8,  '2017-02-01', 'Inventory'),  
(9,  '2017-03-01', 'Inventory'),
```

So I need '2017-01-01' to be the output as its the first date record of a continuous sequence and also its ***LAST*** sequence.

I tried to use standard gaps-and-island solution but couldn't get any success, like on what to apply group by here.

I want to solve the problem using SQL only. I am using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: What are you defining as the criteria for grouping? What constitutes a break? I see duplicate dates but the full scope of your criteria is not defined.

Comment: Also, just a pet peeve of mine... AMBIGUOUS DATES.   Are these YMD or YDM ?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @jw11432: i have added more criteria.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti: these are YMD

Comment: @Isaac: I am using sql server 2008

Answer (score 2):

This indeed is a gaps-and-islands problem. Basically you want the beginning of he last island. Here is one option using window functions:

```
select max(date) res
from (
    select t.*, lag(date) over(partition by type order by Idntty) lag_date
    from mytable t
) t
where lag_date is null or date > dateadd(day, 1, lag_date)
```

In the subquery, `lag()` gives you the date of the "previous" record. Then the outer query filters on rows whose date has a difference greater than 1 day with the previous record (that is, the beginning of each island), and gets the maximum date within this resultset.

Comment: Since the LAG() function is not available in SQL Server 2008 check out the approach of the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22188514/alternate-of-lead-lag-function-in-sql-server-2008).

Comment: Thank you @GMB, when I tried to run this query it gives me the last date '2017-03-01' in the sequence. Actually I need the first date in the last sequence. In my example above, I need '2017-01-01' as the output. I tried to use the min instead of max but then it gave me the first date in the first sequence, that is '2016-03-01'.

Comment: @Isaac: I just checked I would be able to use SQL server 2014 on production.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the looping. try the following:

```
DECLARE CUR CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR SELECT DISTINCT [DATE] FROM @TestData ORDER BY [DATE]
DECLARE @DATE DATE
DECLARE @PREV_DATE DATE = NULL, @FINAL_GRP_DATE DATE, @CN INT = -1
OPEN CUR
FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @DATE
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    IF DATEDIFF(MM, @PREV_DATE, @DATE) = 1
    BEGIN
        SET @FINAL_GRP_DATE = @DATE 
        SET @CN = -1
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @CN = 0
    END
    SET @PREV_DATE = @DATE
    FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @DATE
END
CLOSE CUR
DEALLOCATE CUR

SELECT @FINAL_GRP_DATE
```

Please find the db<>fiddle **[here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=31d77e5fd59eadaca7492752695edb31)**.