# SQL update statement to obtain a column from a previous line row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2008. I would love to be using the latest software but I don't have a say in the matter. I have some data, below is a very simple version of what I am trying to do:

| refNumber | Year |
| --- | --- |
| 123456789 | 2000 |
| 123456789 | 2001 |
| 123456789 | 2002 |
| 223456789 | 2005 |
| 223456789 | 2006 |
| 223456789 | 2007 |

The result I am looking for is the following:

| refNumber | Year | PrevYear |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123456789 | 2000 | NULL |
| 123456789 | 2001 | 2000 |
| 123456789 | 2002 | 2001 |
| 223456789 | 2005 | NULL |
| 223456789 | 2006 | 2005 |
| 223456789 | 2007 | 2006 |

I have tried a few update statements using group by but haven't had much luck. It seems like such a simple thing to do but I am quite the novice in SQL, so any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Alternate of lead lag function in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22188514/alternate-of-lead-lag-function-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: I strongly recommend you upgrade to a newer, supported version

Comment: Thank you but that question was not helpful. I work for a big government organisation in a 3rd world country. I don't get to decide if we upgrade or not. If you only knew what version of Windows I was using.... I have to work with what I have. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a *self* `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select t1.refNumber, t1.Year, t2.Year AS PrevYear
from tablename t1
left join tablename t2 on t1.year = t2.year + 1

                      and t1.refNumber = t2.refNumber
```

(Since your sample data has the same refNumber for all rows, I'm not sure if you want the `and t1.refNumber = t2.refNumber` part or not.)

Comment: Thank you so much, this was simple and worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Lag function to do it like this:

```
SELECT *, 
       Lag(Year, 1) OVER(ORDER BY primaryKey_or_uniqKey ASC) AS PrevYear
FROM tablename ;
```

You can read about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql).

As you said it doesn't exist in Sqlserver 2008, you can do it in this way:

```
With init as (
   SELECT t.*,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY primaryKey_or_uniqKey) AS rn
   FROM tablename t
), result AS (
   SELECT i1.*,
          i2.Year AS LastMonthData
   FROM init AS i1
   LEFT JOIN init AS i2 ON i1.rn = i2.rn + 1
   )
select * from result;
```

Comment: Thanks but Lag and Lead is not available on Sql server 2008. :(

Comment: I edited answer @Milla

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
select a.refNumber
    , a.Year
    , b.Year as PrevYear 
from myTable a 
    left join myTable b on a.Year =  (b.Year+1)
```

Comment: Thank you, I went with jarlh's code. I will keep yours for future reference though!